# Creating simple audio player using the <audio> tag and Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, custom-controls

This is my first question on here, and I'm new to Javascript and jQuery. I've been searching through the web to learn the basics for creating my own functions to the HTML5  tag. I can't get it to function and can't see in my code below where it has gone wrong. I can get it to play using the "controls" addition but would prefer to create my own buttons etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I've gone wrong and what I need to do to get this working?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function init () {
            player = $("#player");
   $("#play").click(play(player));
   $("#pause").click(pause(player));};

function play(player) {
            player.play();
}
function pause(player) {
            player.pause();
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<audio id = "player" src="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">
</audio>
<button id = "play" onclick="document.getElementById("player").play()">Play</button>
<button id = "pause" onclick="document.getElementById("player").pause()">Pause</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use an existing library for that: http://mediaelementjs.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<script = "text/javascript">
```

typo no = sign

Comment: Thanks Haben, I've made the amendment but still couldn't get it to work. I've now added a volume setting to the play function in case it was just too quiet but it still isn't working. I still can't chase the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your jQuery code like the following code

```
function play(player) {
        player.play();
}
function pause(player) {
        player.pause();
}

$(document).ready(function(e){
player = $("#player")[0];
    $("#play").click(function(e){play(player)});
    $("#pause").click(function(e){pause(player)});
});
```